# Reference to value in scope produces garbage

Tags: c++, class, memory, reference, field

I want to write a class with a reference as a field, but am finding that even this simple code which initializes the reference and prints its value fails:

```
struct Referencer {
    explicit Referencer(int in) : num(in) {}
    void print() {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    }
    int &num;
};
int main() {
    int longlived = 500;
    Referencer ref(longlived);
    ref.print();
}
```

The result is garbage (no errors are thrown, nor does the program segfault). My understanding is that the variable `longlived` has the same lifetime as the instance of `Referencer`, as they are both declared in the stack and have the same scope. Therefore, the field `num` should point to valid stack memory when `ref.print()` is called. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Look closely at `Referencer(int in) : num(in)`

Comment: `in` is no longer in scope after you leave the constructor. Maybe you meant `int & in` instead.

Comment: "_My understanding is that the variable `longlived` has the same lifetime as the instance of `Referencer`_" Sure does. But.. Your `Referencer::num` doesn't reference `longlived`.

Comment: welp, my mistake.

Comment: For better understanding, try to do the same with a pointer...

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `Referencer` takes the argument by value. So `in` holds a copy of the value in `longlived`. You then initialized `num` to a reference to `in`, which get's destroyed as soon as the constructor returns.

If you want `num` to hold a reference to the object used as the argument in the constructor, pass `in` by reference like `explicit Referencer(int &in) : num(in) {}`.